# Why are items "jumping" over every other spot in my grid view?

Tags: html, css

//Overview
I'm trying to add items dynamically into my grid and it seems like the items are jumping over every other spot in the grid.

//HBS
[items jumps over grid spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlqaZ.png)

```css
#grid{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 400px);
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }
}
```

```html
    <div class="tile is-ancestor" id="grid" >
        <!-- Create one for each product in database -->             
        <div class="tile is-parent is-one-quarter">
             <article class="tile is-child box">
                 <p class="title">Product Name</p>
                 <p class="subtitle">2000</p>
                 <a href="#" class="button is-primary is-rounded">View</a>
                 <figure class="image is-4by3">
                      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
                  </figure>
             </article>
        </div><br><br>                
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two breaks `<br>` which are also "gridded" because they are direct children of the grid-container. Remove them and you're good to go ;-)